# Organizar pacotes num projeto java

Tags: java, organização-de-projeto

Quando se cria um projeto no `Android`, a própria IDE sugere que o pacote principal tenha um tipo de nomeação própria (com.example.nomedopacote), e também cria toda uma hierarquia de diretórios já definidos.

Assim como acontece no `Android`, há alguma convenção a se seguir ao programar em java (seja desktop ou web), sobre organização e nomenclatura dos pacotes da aplicação, ou somente o MVC é aplicável para este tipo de organização?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A própria Oracle definiu certas convenções para evitar conflitos entre classes Java de diferentes programadores/empresas/projetos.

Ela sugere que uma empresa (ou qualquer programador) utilize seu próprio domínio web invertido como nome dos seus pacotes (visto que o domínio é único). Exemplo: minha empresa possui o domínio `www.empresaficticia.com.br`. O pacote principal dos meus projetos seria definido como segue:

```
package br.com.empresaficticia;
```

Para os casos em que o domínio web não é um nome de pacote válido (possui hífen, pontos, começa com dígitos, etc), a Oracle sugere a utilização do underscore `_`. Exemplo: meu domínio é `www.empresa-ficticia.com.br`, então meu pacote seria:

```
package br.com.empresa_ficticia;
```

Além dessa organização top level sugerida pela Oracle, o resto se torna basicamente opinião e preferência de cada programador/empresa. Uma dica para quando seu projeto ficar muito grande é separá-lo em módulos que tratem de apenas uma categoria de funcionalidades. Exemplo: você possui X classes em seu projeto que lidam apenas com acesso à database, então coloque-as em um sub-pacote `db`:

```
package br.com.empresa_ficticia.db;
```

e um outro sub-pacote poderia se chamar `package br.com.empresa_ficticia.fs;` e conteria suas classes que lidam com arquivos do sistema operacional.

E uma dica final, dê uma olhada em projetos grandes de código aberto. Analise como eles são organizados. Alguns projetos java com os quais já tive contato e recomendo para ter uma maior ideia do assunto: [Apache Hadoop](https://github.com/apache/hadoop), [Apache Giraph](https://github.com/apache/giraph) e [Apache Hama](https://github.com/apache/hama).

Mas antes de sair criando pacotes com nomes que possuam 40 caracteres, uma magia de invocação e o sangue de uma virgem, analise se isso é realmente necessário. Se você estiver apenas fazendo um pet project (projeto para aprender algo novo, que não vai realmente ser utilizado por ninguém), dificilmente vai ser necessário encapsular seu projeto em um pacote.

**Referência:** https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html