# Melhor organização do meu projeto

Tags: java, jsf, mvc

Meu projeto possui os seguintes pacotes na sua estrutura:

- **br.com.xxxx.modelo**:  Que contém as entidades.
- **br.com.xxxx.negocio**: Que contém a interface DAO juntamente com as classes que a implementam.
- **br.com.xxxx.controle**: Que contém os Managed Bean's.
- **br.com.xxxx.util**: Possui as classes utilitárias.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: as minhas classes DAO precisam seguir a implementação DAO, mas dependendo da entidade posso ter comportamentos diferentes, exemplo uma query que possa ter campos diferentes.

Como posso tratar isso? Eu poderia criar uma classe "extra" com essas diferenças?

Comment: Cara, pra ser sincero, acho essa pergunta muito subjetiva, creio que não há uma resposta ideal, cada um pode ter uma opinião, o próprio conceito de MVC já evoluiu muito e qualquer sistema hoje possui muito mais que 3 camadas por exemplo, o que torna tudo mais dinâmico ainda e tudo a gosto do desenvolvedor... (obs, não dei downvote)

Comment: Eu fazia muita perguntas desse tipo, com a experiência eu desencanei. Foque na sua regra de negócio e na entrega de valor ao cliente/usuário. Faça um código bem escrito, que outros programadores entendam, com alta coesão, sem repetição, que está ótimo. Estude, leia e programe que vai chegar na sua solução ideal.

Comment: MVC em Java, certo?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez sim

Comment: Outra pergunta: a construção está seguindo algum *framework* específico ou você está partindo para uma implementação pura?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez estou sim, JSF.

Comment: Não seria duplicata desta aqui? [Organizar pacotes num projeto java](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/114295/28595)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que esse tipo de pergunta é um pouco subjetiva.

É necessário uma outra classe para isso ?
A implementação do DAO é um pouco pessoal também, alguns desenvolvedores "passam a query" que desejam executar em determinado objeto no banco, outros separam dentro da model qual as querys que irão executar, e ao invocar a model passam qual delas quer executar.

Acredito que o mais importante ao se tratar de "padrão" de projeto, é a organização do seu código.

Pergunte-se, ao olhar para esse código daqui alguns meses, ou se uma outra pessoa abrir o seu código, o leitor esperaria que essa código de acesso ao banco estivesse junto dos outros ou numa classe a parte ?

Sendo assim, acredito que cada projeto pede um padrão específico e todo padrão de projeto é um "guide line" não uma regra, desta forma o jeito que você acreditar que seu código está organizado e funcional, será o modo certo.